# Arduino + sim900 + xively

Tags: arduino, gprs, xively, cosm, sim900

I have a problem, I'm new to Arduino and I'm totally a beginner.

I bought a SIM900 Quad-band GSM / GPRS Shield for Arduino (http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=221176159800&ssPageName=ADME:X:RTQ:US:1123) and I have two problems. 
(I use the test code that is found in the library)

First 
the device does not read every message, but only a few. one read and then 3 does not, then 2 read and then 4 do not read .....

Second 
I do not know how to connect to xively, no examples. 
I know how to connect and send data via an ethernet shield, but with SIM900 Quad-band GSM / GPRS Shield do not know how.

**I download the library from** http://www.gsmlib.org/download.html **and fix the first problem with sms**.

but I do not find a solution to the second problem, and I can not find and I need a  **simple example to send data to xively.**

So if anyone can help I would be grateful

Comment: This question should be moved to http://arduino.stackexchange.com/. There should be more help there.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to learn how to have the SIM900 perform HTTP operations. Study the example shown in Step 8 at this [Cooking Hacks tutorial](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/arduino-gprs-gsm-quadband-sim900#step8)

For posting data to Xively, study [this example](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/Arduino/Arduino/libraries/GSM/examples/GSMXivelyClient/GSMXivelyClient.ino).

You'll need to merge how you communicate from the SIM900 with the right HTTP sequences in order to upload data to Xively.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.
I study the example in cooking hack tutorial

but the second example of how to send data to xively is for the original Arduino GPRS library and not for a shield used by sim900

I found an example:

http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GPRS_Shield_V1.0#SoftwareSerial_library_Notes

here is used sim900 with an example how to connect to xively - cosm
but it does not work for me

I download library SoftwareSerial.h but I do not know if I have string.h Where can I download it.
And maybe the problem is that I use the Arduino Mega, so I need something to reconnect

Comment: The Xively example I included was to show you the right types of commands to send to Xively. You'll need to transmit those commands using the right format for a SIM900. Tackle your problems one at a time. Learn how to communicate with the SIM900 before even worrying about Xively. If you're using a current version of the Arduino IDE I don't think you need "string.h"